# KnockoutJS: Execute template in a newly appended DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a large data object that generates a table with lots of long drop down menus. This takes forever, so I am trying to speed up rendering of the table by not rendering all drop down menus on initial load. Instead, I just want to render each menu on demand/click.

```
// HTML Element
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="click: getTags">Tag</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    // Some HTML here
</ul>

// KO Template
<script type="text/html" id="alltags">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data"></a>
</script>

// JS Code
self.getTags = function(data, event) {
    self.availableTags(data.component.available_tags())
    $(event.target).parent().find('ul').prepend('<li data-bind="template: { name: alltags, data: availableTags }"></li>')
}
```

The issue I am having it that DOM element gets prepended to the div as I want it to, but for the life of me I can not get it to execute the `foreach:` loop and generate the menu contents.

Do i need to refresh bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apply bindings will not fire when you add html that way, what I would do is.

Create the dropdowns on load and bind the options to an empty array, when the click event fires populate the empty array with the desired data.

addtl.....

you could create a template that creates your dropdowns and loads them,   then do something like this

```
<!--   ko foreach: templates -->

  <div data-bind:template:{name: tmpl, data:data}></div>
<!--     /ko  -->
```

then use a setTimeout to only load a few at a time, it will still take a while, but will bog down you UI less.

```
function recursive(){
setTimeout(function(){
  // load 5 templates into template array
  check if there are more left, call recursive function to add more
 },50);
}
```

get a little complicated but I have done similar things to fix UI lag in the past

Comment: My god... that was so simple! I must've spent 8 hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: Have to add that it does not really solve my slowness issue. If i render all drop downs on initial page load, it takes about 5 seconds to the table to render. If i use this approach with populating an observableArray on click and then rendering a menu, it takes anywhere from 2 to 5 seconds for each menu to render...

Comment: How many drop downs do you have, how many values in each? (about)

Comment: 56 dropdowns with anywhere from 5 to 120 values (it lists available tags from an SVN server) and I am certain that these dropdowns are slowing everything down. As soon as I comment out the code that renders dropdown menu entries, things start flying.

Comment: That is alot of dropdowns.  Hmm, do you need them all at the same time?  You might be able to use the if binding to only load the ones you need at a given time.

Comment: Yep, I kind of need all of them at the same time. at least the placeholder. This app is for developers to deploy their apps. They pull up the page that contains the list of 56 applications, select version/tag they want to deploy and hit "Save". They deploy anywhere from 1 to 15 apps at once. Dropdowns are populated with list of tags from SVN.

Comment: Did u see my updated response, that's my last idea, but with so many element it may just be memory heavy